# Indexing the topics

Tags: indexing

I have a collection of math contest. 
After each question, i am writing the topics of the question like

```
\index {Cyclic Quadrilateral}
\index {Euler's $\phi$ function}
```

But makeindex refers a page number, not the problem itself. 
How can I achieve such an indexing.

Comment: I guess that the `glossaries` package is what you're looking for.

Answer (score 3):

It is not clear what you want to achieve. To insert the problem number a possibility would be to create a macro (assuming that a `problem` counter exists)

```
\newcommand*{\Tindex}[1]{\index{#1 \arabic{problem}}}
```

A second possibility is to create an index of topics and problems. This can be done using the `index` package.  Here is an example of how to use it (for the documentation of the package use `texdoc index`)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{index}

\newindex[theproblem]*{topics}{pdx}{pnd}{Topics in Problems Index}

\newcounter{problem}

\begin{document}
\setcounter{problem}{1}
\index[topics]{First}First
\newpage
\index[topics]{Second}Second

\setcounter{problem}{2}
\index[topics]{Third}Third
\index[topics]{First}First

\printindex[topics]
\end{document}
```

Then run

```
makeindex -o file.pnd file.pdx
```

where `file` is the name of the LaTeX source file.

Comment: Seems not. `.pnd` and `.pdx` are the suffices of the files as defined in `\newindex` …

Comment: @HarishKumar Tobi is right. It is not a typo. The second and third argument of `\newindex` are the extensions of the index files.